# Parse Push Adapter is not available on my own Parse Server

Tags: android, ios, git, push-notification, parse-server

I am trying to configure push notification from my own Parse Server but receive following exceptions:

```
Android: I/ParseException=﹕ com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Push adapter is not availabe

IOS:[Error]: Push adapter is not availabe (Code: 115, Version: 1.12.0)

HTTP curl -X POST via Terminal: {"code":115,"error":"Push adapter is not available"}
```

As i understand i don't have `ParsePushAdapter` in my server, I am deployed my server on `Heroku/MongoDB` in GitHub repository is parse-server-example. I checked step by step the tutorial on GitHub `https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki`
they says the default implementation is ParsePushAdapter and if i want to implement my own i can add it here

```
  var server = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: '...',
  cloud: '...',
  appId: '...',
  masterKey: '...',
  push: {
    adapter: your_adapter
  }
});
```

I even tryed to add here `adapter:ParsePushAdapter` but it's still the same exceptions.
This is my code:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri,
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY,
  fileKey:'filekey',
  push: {
     android: {
        senderId: 'my sender id',
        apiKey: 'my apiKey'
        },
     ios: [
        {
        pfx: '/developmentcertificate.p12',
        bundleId: 'bundleId',
        production: false // Dev
        },
        {
        pfx: 'distributioncertificate.p12',
        bundleId: 'bundleId',
        production: true // Prod
        }
         ]
  }
});
```

By the way everything else work fine.

Comment: why did you have an extra "/" on the pfx of iOS push setup ?

Comment: it was in folder cer/developmentcertificate.p12 before adding the code on stackoverflow I removed cer/ but in one of them forgot

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the server on Heroku and creating a new one(BE CAREFUL WHILE YOU REMOVING APP ON HEROKU IT'S ALSO REMOVING YOUR DATABASE IF THE DATABASE CREATED ON HEROKU ACCOUNT).